# Flutter on Android Studio cloning from git problem -Package get' has not been run'

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, flutter

has any one faced this problem before ?
when I clone any Flutter project from Git to Android Studio, then try to click on Get Dependencies ,
the operation is completed normally but it does not disappear ,

> Package get' has not been run'

and I cannot also debug it to a Device neither to an AVD !,

,

when I run debug this is the output :

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on SM J410F in debug mode...
[!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
    To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the steps on .
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:186: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:187: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\redoneb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d4c8a434a1d578131ca17eb255940ee5\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          co.appbrewery.dicee\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\redoneb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\3eb4fa90d4b2cfa5cc449030c34cdf03\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\redoneb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\3eb4fa90d4b2cfa5cc449030c34cdf03\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\redoneb\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d4c8a434a1d578131ca17eb255940ee5\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          co.appbrewery.dicee\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\redoneb\AndroidStudioProjects\dicee-flutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and this is a screen-shot : 
[Flutter Android Studio Problem Package get has not been run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHP2S.jpg)

Flutter Doctor output :

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale ar-DZ)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (2 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\redoneb\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\redoneb\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.6.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM J410F • f43a6812 • android-arm • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

this happens with every Flutter project that I clone .

Answer (score 1):

The topic is related to "[The Complete Flutter Development Bootcamp Using Dart](https://www.appbrewery.co/p/flutter-development-bootcamp-with-dart)"

> When something wrong and doesn't work,
>   It's okay in the software development world.

I also had the same issue on Android after cloning and trying to launch them

- https://github.com/londonappbrewery/mi_card_flutter
- https://github.com/londonappbrewery/dicee-flutter
- https://github.com/londonappbrewery/magic-8-ball-flutter
- https://github.com/londonappbrewery/xylophone-flutter
- https://github.com/londonappbrewery/destini-challenge-starting
- https://github.com/londonappbrewery/bmi-calculator-flutter

**So, here are steps to get rid of the problem**

**1)** your-cool-flutter-project/android/app/build.gradle

In this file be sure that you have 29 API used two times if you see 27 then modify to 29 like these

```
  compileSdkVersion 29
  targetSdkVersion 29
```

**2)**  your-cool-flutter-project/android/gradle.properties

Check that file has these two lines if they miss then add them

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

> That's all. Take a breath. Relax. And launch the app =)

- I very hope you have the latest Android and Flutter installed ;)*

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie to android studio and flutter development. I was trying out the same dicee flutter app by cloning it on my machine. I don't know exactly what the problem was, but in my  *android/gradle/build.gradle* file of the cloned project I edited the following line

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

to

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

which was similar to the projects created by me offline. This might be due to running an older version of this gradle stuff on my machine. I am not sure but it worked for me for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before I don't know why it happens but what I do is close the project and open it again and that seems to solve my problem.

Comment: do you close the project or the program ?,and do you close it after clicking 'Package get' ?

Comment: I close the project (that's the only project opened) and I do that after I have clicked on 'Packages get'

Answer (score 0):

Or just clone fixed repos =)

https://github.com/maxeema/dicee-flutter

https://github.com/maxeema/mi_card_flutter

https://github.com/maxeema/magic-8-ball-flutter

https://github.com/maxeema/xylophone-flutter

https://github.com/maxeema/destini-challenge-starting

https://github.com/maxeema/bmi-calculator-flutter